# Android - access Thread instantiated in a service

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I want to instantiate a thread in a Service that will work even when the client leaves the app. On his return the Tread will not be instantiated again only certain parameters of it may be changed. So I need to be able to access it. It also concerns rotation of the screen.

The current code starts another thread which is obviously not a desired solution. The commented out stuff shows different approaches but they didn't work either. I will have to access threadService object in main activity as well.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static ThreadService threadService;
private ServiceConnection threadConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        ThreadServiceBinder binder = (ThreadServiceBinder) service;
        threadService = binder.getService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThreadService.class);
    this.startService(intent);


/*      if(threadConnection == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThreadService.class);
        this.startService(intent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Thread service is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        if(!threadService.ifThreadIsRunning()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThreadService.class);
            this.startService(intent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Thread service is not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }*/
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    this.stopService(new Intent(this, ThreadService.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}
/*
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}*/
```

}

Here is the service

```
public class ThreadService extends Service {

private final IBinder threadServiceBinder = new ThreadServiceBinder();

public class ThreadServiceBinder extends Binder {
    ThreadService getService() {
        return ThreadService.this;
    }
}

final Handler handler = new Handler();

private BackgroundThread backgroundThread;

public ThreadService() {
    /*
     * if(backgroundThread == null) backgroundThread =new
     * BackgroundThread(handler);
     */
    backgroundThread = BackgroundThread.getInstance();
    backgroundThread.setHandler(handler);
    handler.removeCallbacks(backgroundThread);
    handler.postDelayed(backgroundThread, 10000);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return threadServiceBinder;
}

public boolean ifThreadIsRunning() {
    if (backgroundThread.isAlive()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

}

class BackgroundThread extends Thread {
private static BackgroundThread instance;
private Handler mHandler;

private BackgroundThread() {
}

public static synchronized BackgroundThread getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new BackgroundThread();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
    if (mHandler == null) {
        mHandler = handler;
    }
}

/*
 * public BackgroundThread(Handler handler) { super(); mHandler = handler; }
 */
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Log.d("com.example.timer", "We are in Runnable run try section");
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    /*
     * finally{ handler.postDelayed(runable, 2000); }
     */
}
}
```

Comment: where is bindService called?

Comment: I have added this in onCreate method - this.bindService(intent, threadConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); but it didn't work... still starts many threads whenever I open the app again.